# Meaning of "amore honora, libertatem cura"

Tags: sentence-translation, latin-to-english-translation

What is the closest meaning of this statement?

Single comma there is intentional, it's not an enumeration.  I understand that liberty cures, but struggling to connect the two words in first part.

Comment: Are you sure the first word is _amore_ and not _amorem_?

Comment: Yes, what's the difference?

Comment: Is amorem correct spelling or it has different meaning?

Comment: Source/context would be helpful .

Comment: @MaxTsepkov Welcome to the site! In Latin nouns change grammatical function (meaning, in short) with endings, just as verbs in English do. The ending of an English verb changes tense, _amorem_ here would make _amor_ (love) the object of _honora_, the verb; just as _libertatem_ is the object of _cura_.

Comment: Like Fdb, I must insist on more context. Because, without context, this phrase seems bad Latin, and people are doing their utmost to make something out of it; with context, it would probably be easier to tell whether it was just bad Latin or something that made sense. And we mean context in the broadest sense: anything you know could help. Did you make up this phrase yourself? Is it from Google Translate? From a poem? An fragment from an inscription? Would it make sense for us to reconstruct omitted words or not?

Comment: After discussing this question with another moderator, I have put it on hold, because we normally require translation questions to include (enough) context if possible. It will be reopened when some context is added.

Comment: @cerberus, unfortunately I do not have a context. It's a tattoo on a girl's hand so any guess is helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

*honoro* means 'cherish,' 'show respect' " to clothe or adorn with honor; to honor, respect; to adorn, ornament, embellish, decorate." (Tufts [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DH%3Aentry%20group%3D17%3Aentry%3Dhonoro))
The Accusative *Libertatem,* Liberty, shows what is honoured, respected 
 With the Ablative it shows how respect is shown (with a ceremony: *Suetonius* or with a gift, or a position/ or status *Vet. Patr.*  see esp. "to honour virtue" Cicero Philippics 9/2/4)

*Cura* is the tricky word.
If it is from the verb *curo* 'care for,' 'look after,' these are two imperatives,  two maxims to be followed. These are the two obligations, the personal and the civic.

> amore honora, libertatem cura,
>   Show respect by means of love, take good care of freedom.

**II** But if it is the noun: *cura,* "trouble, care, attention, pains, industry, diligence, exertion." wh., is **statistically more likel**y (see [perseus tufts Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=c%C5%ABra&la=la&can=c%C5%ABra0&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:alphabetic%20letter=C:entry%20group=122:entry=cura&i=1)) Then *amore, cura,* (asyndeton) together mean "with love, with diligence."

> amore honora, libertatem cura,
>   With love, with care show your respect for freedom.

Answer (score 2):

A way to make sense of the phrase as a whole is if the context is religious. This could be a piece of an explanation of the [Fourth Commandment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honour_thy_father_and_thy_mother):

> **honora patrem tuum et matrem**/*Honour thy father and thy mother* (Ex 20:12, Eph 6:2)

It would make a lot of sense if it is trying to explain that one has to honor one's parents with love, aiming to grow up to be free, autonomous adults. This, while continuing to love them.

My translation in that case would be:

> *Honor* [them/your parents] *with love,* [but] *pursue* [your] *freedom*.

Even if it is not an explanation of the fourth commandment, it makes the most sense to me if translated this way.

---

Regarding *liberty cures*, I'm afraid it is not quite a suitable translation, since I think the verb **curo** would need to be in 3rd person: (e.g., **curat**, or something else ending in **-t**).

Answer (score 1):

The first part could be an abl. absol. giving--"with love having been honest" in the sense of "free from deceit". The second part (agree with Hugh) seems only tenuously linked to the first, requiring a colon; not, a comma.

Comment: That is creative! So you would have to assume an adjective *honorus*, which does indeed exist. The only problem is that *amor* is masculine, so it would have to be *honoro* then.

Comment: @Cerberus What if you referred to a woman as "my love"? I guess it'd make sense to treat *amor* as feminine then. But that'd take the whole translation in a new direction, too...

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: I'm afraid it would still have to be masculine, then, as it would only refer to a female person metaphorically.

Comment: @Cerberus: Thanks: tend to think of "love" as feminine: back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Joonasllmavirta: thanks for (almost) saving me; but, there's no fooling Cerberus.